# put prop conditionally, if <Wrapper> is a div I don't want to send anything. const Wrapper = to ? Link : 'div'; <Wrapper to={to ? to : undefined} >

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to generate a tag dynamically `<Link> | <div>`. If there is a route in the `to` constant, I would like to add `to` prop to this component (`<Wrapper>`), otherwise, I don't want to have anything prop.

```
<Link to="/home"> //prop to
<div>
```

I have **typing problems**, which I would like to know how to solve.

The problem is in the prop `to`, please I would appreciate if you see the link to my live code, the error says something like  `to` can not be `undefined`. how can I correct it? thanks.

my code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Link } from "gatsby";

export default function App() {
  const to = "/home";
  const Wrapper = to ? Link : "div";

  return (
    <Wrapper to={to ? to : undefined}>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

It is my live code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-night-ugugi

Note:  code does nothing at this moment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `React.createElement` here

If `to` is truthy then It will create a `Link` type component and pass the prop as `{ to }`.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Link } from "gatsby";

export default function App() {
  const to = "/home";
  const Wrapper = to ? Link : "div";
  const props = to ? { to }: null;

  return React.createElement(
    Wrapper,
    props,
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```